# Formula to assign "Score" of one item to a different item in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have three fields called "UniqueID" "Relationship" and "Score".

Relationship:

```
Self 
Boss 
Peer 
Direct Report 
Other
```

I need to merge the Scores from "Others" and "Peer" into one group labeled "Peers"
and
I need to merge the "UniqueID" from "Others" and "Peer" into the "UniqueID" for "Peers"

Essentially I want to merge "others" into "Peers"

This seems like it is a easy thing to do but after 2hrs of trying I thought I would ask for help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using the relationship field, create a formula and use that instead:

`if {table.relationship}="Other" then "Peer" else {table.relationship}`

Comment: Hello Ryan, I tried your suggestion it did not give me what I was after, do to my inept description not you code.  I modified my question to (I hope) express what I am after better.  Thanks

Comment: @Tim What's not working? If you use this formula field then each `Other` row will behave exactly as a `Peer` row. Keep in mind, ALL references in the report should point to this new formula field instead of the relationship field.

Comment: Thank Ryan, I had not quit gotten all the groupings and formula changes all modified correctly.  Thanks again!!!